# How can i get the owner name in a formula field

Tags: apex, formula

I am trying to write a formula field which will pick the Owner name ... but currently the id is being displayed in the formula field. Is thr any way to capture this

can plz anyone help me...
Thanx in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try do the following, which will get the First and Last Name.

```
Owner:User.FirstName & ' ' & Owner:User.LastName
```

I got a `Field Name does not exist` error when I tried to do `Owner:User.Name`

Comment: no it is giving me wrong answer 
but ya i made it by 
Owner.FirstName & ' ' & Owner.LastName

Answer (score 8):

Owner is a tricky field because on some objects (like Case or any custom object) it's a polymorphic field, meaning that it can refer to either a User or a Queue. On others (like Account), only Users can be owners.

So it will be one of the following.

Not polymorphic:

```
User.FirstName & " " & User.LastName
```

Polymorphic, not using Queues:

```
Owner:User.FirstName & " " & Owner:User.LastName
```

Polymorphic, using Queues. This checks whether Owner:Queue.Id is empty: if it is, then the owner is a User and it returns the user's name; otherwise, the owner is a Queue and it returns the queue's name.

```
IF( 
  ISBLANK(Owner:Queue.Id),
  Owner:User.FirstName & " " & Owner:User.LastName,
  Owner:Queue.QueueName
)
```